# Download file from AWS S3 using fetch method throws CORS error

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors, fetch

I added below s3 config to my AWS S3 bucket cors setting.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://*.herokuapp.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Now when I am trying to read it using below JS, I am getting error.

```
async function covertToBlob(url) {
  // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html
  const resp = await fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'include',
  });
  const blobVal = await resp.blob();
  return blobVal;
}
```

Error is:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://dhdhddh.s3.amazonaws.com/docs/attachment/6f56abfe-a355-44b9-b728-a642f661a8e7/file/3ed4e889-e139-4755-81e9-5383310e07e7/remote_sounding_system_Hanla.pdf'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
> must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
> 'include'.

Would you give me some ideas about how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included

> Note: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is prohibited from using a wildcard for requests with credentials: 'include'. In such cases, the exact origin must be provided; even if you are using a CORS unblocker extension, the requests will still fail.

That means, the value for `AllowedOrigins` *must not* contain *any* wildcard character. You *must* specify the *exact* origin.

This is per the Fetch API specification.

Comment: Means in the CORS rule? Can I change the JS without changing the CORS rule to make it work?

Comment: If I don't use `credentials: 'include'` option then I get `403`.

Comment: Yes you are right. Once I added the origin it started working. Thanks for your time. It made sense later what you asked me to do. Me got old. -_-